# Check constraint failing in one database

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I have a table which do have a check constraint in one of it's field. 
check constraint is defined as `(([WID]%(3)+(1))=(1))`.

I have different environments. In one of the environment's database if i try to insert `WID 2000` it's throwing error saying `check constraint failed`.  In other environments it's working fine. 
If i try with any other values 4000,5000 it's working fine. I don't know the logic for that `check constraint` since i newly joined this team.

As per my calculation, if we give 5000 also this `constraint` should fail. But it's working for all other values. 
Any idea or clue?

Comment: Just a curious question... What is the data type of that [WID] column?

Comment: [wid] datatype is int

Comment: Why would 3000 fail? Not sure why you have so many parenthesis here. Or why you bother adding 1. That could be simplified to WID % 3 = 0. In other words what you have coded there means the value of WID must be divisible by 3. No idea why you think 3000 is not divisible by 3.

Comment: I get that `3000%3+1=1` so why would you expect the constraint to fail?

Comment: ".. since I newly joined this team" Go ask YOUR TEAM what it does.

Comment: You're saying that this works in one environment but not in another. Are you sure both environments really have the same constraint? The same constraint cant behave different in different environments. Something more must be different.

Comment: I misread your question. Sorry about that. I agree with all above commenters. According to the logic of the check constraint, all multiples of 3 should be valid values. Values 4000 and 5000 should fail. If they do not fail, the only thing I can think of is an INSTEAD OF trigger that manipulates the [WID] value before inserting it physically... But in that case, you should be able to see that manipulated value if you perform a SELECT query on the table...

Comment: No idea what you are asking here. You need to help us understand what the problem is.

Comment: Could your check constraint simply be disabled on other environments? i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-check-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-2017